# How to programmatically remove PDF layers?

Tags: pdf, layer, ocg

I know about [`Doc.SetOCGOrder()`](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=JS_API_AcroJS.88.482.html) and the likes, but apparently the Acrobat API does not provide means to remove layers (aka optional content groups, ocgs), only to hide them from users while leaving them accessible via scripting.

I'm not forced to use Acrobat, in fact I'd prefer a FOSS-solution (or at least freeware) using e.g. [pypdf2](/questions/tagged/pypdf2) or [pdftk](/questions/tagged/pdftk). **edit** There is [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2498883/321973) using [abcpdf](/questions/tagged/abcpdf), which is unfortunately not free. Is there any way to port that behaviour to Acrobat's JS or [pypdf2](/questions/tagged/pypdf2)? Essentially the answer seems to loop through every page's content, which seems to include the layers.

(Concerning merging, I notice `pdftk` does remove layers when merging multiple files, so one can simple `pdftk A=input.pdf B=input.pdf cat A1-end output output.pdf`.)

Comment: WIP-idea: Make layers invisible first, then use `pdftk` to merge. But does that truly delete the layer content?

Comment: Do you want to remove the content of the layer together with its definition or do you merely want to remove the information that that content is in a layer? Furthermore, solutions for which programming environments are you interested in?

Comment: @mkl I want to truly remove the layer's content. Otherwise I could use Acrobat's API and change the properties (though I'm not sure whether I'd have to simply use `locked` and `initState` or modify/empty the `intents` - in fact, https://www.uvsar.com/projects/acrobat/indesignfixups/ suggests I'd have to "remove" it via `setOCGOrder`).

Comment: In that case you might want to use the iText (a Java PDF library) utility class `OCGRemover`, cf. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17718641/1729265).

Comment: @mkl Thanks, I'll have a look at it as well

Answer (score 0):

My approach so far: For the relevant layers obtained via `GetOCGs()` set `locked=true` and both `initState=false` and `state=false`. Then use `SetOCGOrder()` to remove the layer from the layers view. Unfortunately this is not perfect, since at least in Acrobat DC I can still select "show all layers" in the layers panel, which still shows the layer. One could merge all layers now, but neither did I find an option to achieve that programmatically nor do I believe that would actually remove the hidden layer's elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it programmatically but you can create an Action that will process a folder full of PDF files using Adobe Acrobat. Set the Action to use the PDF Optimizer to discard hidden layers and flatten visible ones. See the graphic.

[image]